# How to Insert a large amount of money into a database using T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql

Really simple question, I'm relatively new to SQL. I have a large amount of money that I need to store in my database such as £14,567,543. How would I go about to do this, I am already using DECMIAL(19,4). I just need to know the layout such as would I insert it using a period to split up the number or with a comma.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't store it in database but on in your bank account ;)

Comment: So you're telling me I can't just throw my money at the screen?

Comment: What is the type that you are trying to insert, maybe string? Convert it to a real decimal before you insert it.

Comment: I'm trying to insert it as a decimal

Comment: Hire a very expensive database consultant. :) Sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: Just insert it as a decimal. There are no commas or formats. Just a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, You can convert it to `MONEY` first and then do a conversion to `DECIMAL` like this.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,4),CONVERT(MONEY,'£14,567,543') )
```